# Bootstrap Vertical timeline to Horizontal timeline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a vertical timeline that needs to be changed completely into horizontal timeline I'm trying to get it horizontal but it doesn't work as expected.

Posted the complete CSS & HTML code also link to codepen of the current progress.

Also, the timeline needs to be responsive in horizontal view.

**Link**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvPLrP

```css
#Timline {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Timline-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-item {
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-box:after {
  left: -20px;
  right: auto;
  border-color: transparent;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 10px solid #fff;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
}

.Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-icon {
  right: auto;
  left: -32px;
}

.Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-year {
  text-align: right;
  right: 140%;
  left: auto;
}

.Timline-holder:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  background: #939393;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.Timline-item {
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.Timline-year {
  top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 140%;
}

.Timline-year>* {
  margin: 0;
}

.Timline-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -28px;
  top: 72px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.Timline-icon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Timline-icon:hover {
  color: #E3000F;
  border: 2px solid #E3000F;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.Timline-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.Timline-box h3,
.Timline-box h5 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.Timline-box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 40px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}

.Timline-box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.Timline-box:hover+.Timline-icon {
  color: #E3000F;
  border: 2px solid #E3000F;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.Timline-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* Timline  Responsive */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .Timline-year {
    left: 152%;
  }
  .Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-year {
    right: 152%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .Timline-item {
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .Timline-holder:before {
    left: 37px;
  }
  .Timline-icon {
    left: -60px;
    right: auto;
    top: 42px;
  }
  .Timline-year {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Timline-box:after {
    left: -20px;
    right: auto;
    border-color: transparent;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff;
    border-left-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-item {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    float: none;
  }
  .Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-icon {
    left: -60px;
    right: auto;
  }
  .Timline-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .Timline-year {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Timline Section -->
<section id="Timline">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-content">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Section Title -->
        <div class="col-md-12 section-title text-center">
          <span class="divider center"></span>
          <h2>Timline</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Section Title -->
        <!-- Timline-1 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class="Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>One</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-paint-brush"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-1 -->
        <!-- Timline-2 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Two</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-star"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-2 -->
        <!-- Timline-3 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Three</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-3 -->
        <!-- Timline-4 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Four</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-star"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-4 -->
        <!-- Timline-5 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Five</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-paint-brush"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-5 -->
        <!-- Timline-6 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Six</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-star"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-6 -->
        <!-- Timline-7 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Seven</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-7 -->
        <!-- Timline-8 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Eight</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-star"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-8 -->
        <!-- Timline-9 -->
        <div class="Timline-wrapper">
          <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                  <h3>Nine</h3>
                </div>
                <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Timline-9 -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End of Timline Section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this based on your requirement

```css
/* Timeline */

.timeline,
.timeline-horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline:before {
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:before,
.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
  color: #fff;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #7c7c7c;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge i,
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .fa,
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge .glyphicon {
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.primary {
  background-color: #1f9eba;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.success {
  background-color: #59ba1f;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.warning {
  background-color: #d1bd10;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-badge.danger {
  background-color: #ba1f1f;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 46%;
  float: left;
  right: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 16px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 0 solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>p,
.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item .timeline-panel .timeline-body>p+p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:last-child:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel {
  float: right;
  left: 16px;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:nth-child(even) .timeline-panel:before {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 14px;
  left: -14px;
  right: auto;
}

.timeline-horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.timeline-horizontal:before {
  height: 3px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 26px;
  left: 56px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 280px;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 320px;
  float: none !important;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 64px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-panel:before {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 28px !important;
  right: auto;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent !important;
  border-top: 16px solid #c0c0c0 !important;
  border-bottom: 0 solid #c0c0c0 !important;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent !important;
}

.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:before,
.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item:after {
  display: none;
}

.timeline-horizontal .timeline-item .timeline-badge {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 43px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Horizontal timeline</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <ul class="timeline timeline-horizontal">
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>One</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Two</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Three</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Four</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Five</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Six</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Seven
                    </h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Eight</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeline-item">
            <div class="col-md-12 Timline-holder">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 Timline-item">
                  <div class=" Timline-box" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h3>Nine</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class=" Timline-icon fa fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```